# How do I assign a value to an enum in constructor with a default value?

Tags: c++, enums, constructor

I have a class in C++ with a protected enum type and I am having trouble initialising that value in the constructor using a user defined argument, where it also has a default value.

Code:

```
class Student
{
protected:
  double gpa;
  enum gradeStatus {freshman, sophomore, junior, senior, blank};
public:
  Student(double inGPA = 0.0, gradeStatus inGrade = blank)
  :
  gpa(inGPA),
  gradeStatus(inGrade) //problem here
  {}
};
```

I am getting a compiler error due to the statement `gradeStatus(inGrade)`:

Error (active)  E0292   "gradeStatus" is not a nonstatic data member or base class of class "Student"

I want the emum to have a default value of `blank` if the `Student` object is created without supplying a `gradeStatus` value and if they do, then I want to initilize the `Student` object with the user supplied parameter.

Any help on how I can do that appreciated.

Comment: `enum gradeStatus` does not do what you think it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gradeStatus` is the name of enum type, but not a name of data member. The error message is trying to tell you that you should initialize a data member, but not a enum type.

You might want

```
class Student
{
protected:
  double gpa;
  enum gradeStatus {freshman, sophomore, junior, senior, blank}; // enum type definition
  gradeStatus status;                                            // data member definition
public:
  Student(double inGPA = 0.0, gradeStatus inGrade = blank)
  :
  gpa(inGPA),
  status(inGrade) // initialize the data member
  {}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gradeStatus(inGrade)
```

This line tries to assign inGrade to gradeStatus. “gradeStatus” is an enum type, and not a member of the class. To solve this, add a member to your class, for example:

```
gradeStatus status;
```

And then change the problematic line to:

```
status(inGrade)
```